# How to increase and then decrease a variable

Tags: c#

I do to first increase the variable to 30, and then reduce it to -30, and then increase it back to 30.But I did it so that it only increases, and then I don’t know how to reduce the same variable

```
public float RotationCar = 1;
if (RotationCar < 30)
{
    RotationCar += Time.deltaTime * 2;
}
if (RotationCar > 30)
{
    RotationCar -= Time.deltaTime * 2;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you are using Unity, as you have not stated what `Time.deltaTime` is. You can use a flag for that:

```
private bool increase = true;

if (increase)
{
    if (RotationCar < 30)
        RotationCar += Time.deltaTime * 2;
    else
        increase = false;
}
else
{
    if (RotationCar > -30)
        RotationCar -= Time.deltaTime * 2;
    else
        increase = true;
}
```

This way `RotationCar` is increased until its value is >= 30, after that the flag is set to `false` so that the value is decreased in consecutive calls  to `Update` until its value is <= -30. Then the flag is set to `true` and the process is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever `Time.deltaTime` is (you use it as it were always positive, so I assume it is :)), you are close to your goal, it is enough to replace `if` with `while`:

```
    public float RotationCar = 1;
    while (RotationCar < 30)
        RotationCar += Time.deltaTime * 2;

    while (RotationCar > -30)
        RotationCar -= Time.deltaTime * 2;
```

Sp first loop executeds as long as `RotationCar < 30`, increasing variable on every iteration.

Analogically with second loop, it lowers variable as long as it is bigger than -30.

Comment: For some reason, it works only to decrease and does not work to increase

Comment: It works, but if you ran everything at once, you will get negative value at the end. You have to split that code to two parts.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some state variable to let you program keep reducing to -30 even if carrotation is less than 30, it can be some enum

```
    public float RotationCar = 1;
    public State StateCar = State.Increasing;
    if (StateCar == State.Increasing )
    {
        if (RotationCar < 30) 
        {
            RotationCar += Time.deltaTime * 2;
        }
        else 
        {
             StateCar = State.Decreasing;
        }
    }
    if (StateCar == State.Decreasing) 
    {
        if (RotationCar > -30)
        {
            RotationCar -= Time.deltaTime * 2;
        }
        else 
        {
             StateCar = State.Increasing;
        }
     }
```